# How can I get worksheet code name to activate a specific worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have a worksheet with the "tab" name of "Rpt_Group". I also renamed its code name to shData.  When I use VBA to activate the worksheet using "Rpt_Group" it runs fine. But when I use the code name I get an error message

> "subscript out of range.

This works: `WBA.Worksheets("Rpt_Group").Activate`

This does not work: `WBA.Worksheets("shData").Activate`

This does not work: `WBA.shData.Activate`

```
Dim WBA As Workbook

'Open the desired workbook
Set WBA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="path & file name")

'Activate the desired worksheet
WBA.Worksheets("Rpt_Group").Activate 'this works
```

This does not work: `WBA.Worksheets("shData").Activate`

This does not work: `WBA.shData.Activate`

Comment: I'd advise against using codenames in VBA code: It solves possible sheet renaming issues, but can give you more headaches if a sheet is deleted and you try and use it by ist codename! What's your actual need to activate a sheet by its codename?

Comment: Ironically, the only reason I was trying to use code names was that I read a post on another help website and it recommended using code names instead of sheet names!  I think I'm going to stick with sheet names. Thanks.

Comment: could you share that post link?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution:

```
Sub tester()
    Dim WBA As Workbook

    Set WBA = Workbooks("Book1")
    WorksheetByCodeName(WBA, "codeNameHere").Activate

End Sub

'Get a worksheet with matching codeName (or Nothing if no match)
'    from a workbook wb
Function WorksheetByCodeName(wb As Workbook, codeName As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rv As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.codeName = codeName Then
            Set rv = ws
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
    Set WorksheetByCodeName = rv
End Function
```

Probably want to check the return value before trying to do anything with it.

Comment: I'm new to VBA so this may be a dumb response. But I was trying to get away from using worksheet names and instead use the worksheet code name. Doesn't the line of code above:

Comment: I'm new to VBA so this may be a dumb response. But I was trying to get away from using worksheet names and instead use the worksheet code name. From what I understand, the worksheet name is "Sheet3" and I changed the code name to "shData".  I don't understand how the vba code above allows me to use the code name instead of the sheet name.  Thanks very much for your response.

Comment: Instead of "Sheet3" you'd use whatever your sheet codename is - my post is just an example to show how it can be done.