# Call a named worksheet (in visual basic) from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The question is simple, see in the photo :

[image: I want to read two sheets of an workbook as two arrays so that I can close it and use data directly in another workbook(Main)]

In the workbook itself, we can reference the sheet directly like this:

```
Synthese.Range("bla:bla")
```

instead of

```
Worksheets("Sythèse FGA").Range("bla:bla")
```

So I really just want to write a fonction to get an excel file by file dialogue, and then read two sheets into arrays so that I can close this workbook.

Of course I don't need to do like this, I just want to know if it's possible.

Comment: If you want to refer to a sheet in a different workbook by its codename, then perhaps see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549008/how-can-i-get-worksheet-code-name-to-activate-a-specific-worksheet).

Comment: @BigBen, yeah, that's what I am doing nowadays, I am just wondering.

Comment: this is a "hacky" method and comes with its own issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256536/referencing-sheets-in-another-workbook-by-codename-using-vba

Comment: [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44777242/4851590) answer also explains the trust you will need to add